# MySQL Interval Issue Extra Results

Tags: mysql

I manged to get my query together to select the past 7 days, and I modified it so it is supposed to select the past 7 days from the date I enter instead of `NOW()`, however when I do this, it is producing results 7 days prior to the date, and then every entry AFTER the date:

```
date Ascending
2016-10-02
2016-10-03
2016-10-05
2016-10-06
2016-10-07
2016-10-17
2016-10-18
2016-10-20
2016-10-21
2016-10-22
2016-10-23
```

When it should be exporting:

```
date Ascending
2016-10-02
2016-10-03
2016-10-05
2016-10-06
2016-10-07
```

The query:

```
SELECT DATE
FROM  `dates` 
WHERE DATE > (  '2016-10-08' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
ORDER BY  `date`
```

I appreciate your assistance, I simply cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then add an extra criteria to the `where` clause to cap the returned records at the date specified:

```
WHERE DATE > (  '2016-10-08' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) AND DATE <= '2016-10-08'
```

Any date after the specified date will be greater than 1 week before the specified date, therefore you need to have the additional criterion.

Comment: Your magical and wonderful - this worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: A well written question deserves an answer :)